# Area Under Curve (not ROC)

Tags: cross-validation, python, auc

I'm coming across a metrics for model evaluation which I had never seen before and I don't know how to further research (since I don't know its proper name).

I'm using someone else's code, whose goal is to perform cross-validation to choose the best tree-based algorithm for a binary classification. It is probably worth saying that classes are highly skewed (93% / 7%). The metric which is used is the following: the classifier is trained and then the probability associated with each test element is computed.

```
probas = probas[:,list(clf.classes_).index(1)]
```

Then, these probabilities are ordered from the highest to the lowest and put on the x-axis. On the y-axis, the cumulative sum of entries associated with each probability is put. Then, they compute the area under the obtained curve, as in:

```
joint = zip(probas, truth)
joint = sorted(list(joint), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)
probas = [x[0] for x in joint]
truth = [x[1] for x in joint]
# Calculate accumulated number of true labels at each probability point.
# Also calculate Area Under Curve (AUC) (higher is better model)
truth_cumulative = np.cumsum(truth) / np.sum(truth)
area = np.trapz(truth_cumulative, dx=1) / len(truth)
```

Can anyone give me an intuition of what this metric is about and a pointer to some resources to better understand it?

Thanks.

[Edit] The used clf is a Classification Tree. Probabilities are directly retrieved from the model as in `probas = clf.predict_proba(X_test)`

Comment: Your `truth_cumulative` is the predicted cumulative distribution function $\hat{F}_i$ for the $i$th test observation, evaluated at the actual observation $y_i$, or $\hat{F}_i(y_i)$. This reminds me of the *ranked probability score*, which is a proper [tag:scoring-rules]. You may want to read up on the two. However, calculating the area under this curve stumps me. A priori, the $\hat{F}_i$ are not even comparable, so it doesn't even make sense to order the $\hat{F}_i(y_i)$ in ascending order, much less calculate the area under the curve. ...

Comment: ... I suspect someone has built a homegrown scoring rule, but did not notice it is improper. It might be a nice exercise to create an example where it is misleading.

Comment: As Stephan suggested, I think that this is closely related to the *continuous ranked probability score* (CRPS) which corresponds to the integral of the Brier scores for the associated binary probability forecasts at all real-valued thresholds. You may want to check the paper *"Strictly Proper Scoring Rules, Prediction, and Estimation"* from  Gneiting and Raftery. I suspect that the "integral" is used to get an average but actually the scoring scheme here is improper. (cont.)

Comment: For example, if we assume: `truth  = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)` and `probas1 = (0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8)` and `probas2 = (0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.65)` it is immediately clear that `probas1` is a more reliable classifier. Nevertheless the AUC score associated with these two set of predictions is the same.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the comments.  
Yes, the scoring rule sounded a bit "counter-intuitive" to me, so I wanted to double-check if it was some kind of well-known scoring system and where it came from. Also, thanks for suggesting the paper and to redirect me to the ranked probability score, I'll check that out asap.